# Reboot Android Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I have Android on a Pixel 5 on the standard Android Emulator inside Android Studio. I just want to restart the phone using the power button like a normal Android user. However,  clicking the power button just makes the screen go blank like this:

[image]

Clicking it again just wakes it up, and holding it down brings this up:

[image]

Most of the documentation I've seen tells me to do a cold boot, but when I do, I see this.

[image]

So, I delete these two files and try cold boot again. Android Studio displays some text that says something like "Start AVD now" but nothing happens. The phone does not restart.

I cannot find any way to restart the OS. It's jammed in one spot. I've deleted and recreated image after image without any way to restart the phone. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on the dots menu on the emulator row on **Device Manager** you will find the option **Cold Boot Now**.

Alternatively, you can use

```
adb reboot
```